# Openlayers 3 ol.extent to ol.geom.Polygon conversion

Tags: geometry, openlayers, extents

In openlayers 2 there was a method "toGeometry()" on Openlayers.Bounds() that could convert that bounds into a Geometry. I migrated from ol2 to ol3 and I try to find a solution to easily do the same thing without having to define a ring with all the coordinates and then using the constructor of ol.geom.Polygon(ring). The API is not helping.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(extent)](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html?unstable=true#fromExtent).

Try to uncheck the "Stable Only" checkbox in the API docs to see all methods.